# Move columns in a pivoted data frame or move to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current code im working with:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['01/07/2020', '21:30', 3176.5, 3195, 3176.5, 3192, 21116],
        ['01/07/2020', '22:00', 3192.25, 3193.25, 3184, 3192, 13472],
        ['01/07/2020', '22:30', 3192.25, 3193, 3188.25, 3192.75, 6104],
        ['01/07/2020', '23:00', 3192.75, 3194.5, 3190.75, 3191.25, 2704],
        ['01/07/2020', '23:30', 3191, 3191.5, 3188.75, 3189, 1663]]

# Create a DataFrame from the data list
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

# Pivot the DataFrame
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Time', values=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

print(pivoted_df)
```

which outputs:

```
              Open                                       High                                      Low                                      Close                                     Volume
Time         21:30    22:00    22:30    23:00   23:30   21:30    22:00   22:30   23:00   23:30   21:30   22:00    22:30    23:00    23:30   21:30   22:00    22:30    23:00   23:30    21:30    22:00   22:30   23:00   23:30
Date
01/07/2020  3176.5  3192.25  3192.25  3192.75  3191.0  3195.0  3193.25  3193.0  3194.5  3191.5  3176.5  3184.0  3188.25  3190.75  3188.75  3192.0  3192.0  3192.75  3191.25  3189.0  21116.0  13472.0  6104.0  2704.0  1663.0
```

Is it possible to move the open, high, low, last, volume next to each other for each time like below

Desired output:

```
        Date         21:30 Open  21:30 High  21:30 Low  21:30 Last  21:30 Volume  22:00 Open  22:00 High  22:00 Low  ...  23:00 High  23:00 Low  23:00 Last  23:00 Volume  23:30 Open  23:30 High  23:30 Low  23:30 Last  23:30 Volume
0    01/07/2020        3176.5      3195.0     3176.5      3192.0       21116.0     3192.25     3193.25     3184.0  ...      3194.5    3190.75     3191.25        2704.0      3191.0      3191.5    3188.75      3189.0        1663.0
```

Comment: `pivoted_df.columns = [f'{y} {x}' for x,y in pivoted_df.columns]`

Answer (score 1):

Seems the simplest way is the comment by Quang Hoang.

If it have to look like the desired output, use `sort_index`.

```
pivoted_df.columns = [f'{y} {x}' for x,y in pivoted_df.columns]
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.sort_index(axis = 1)
pivoted_df
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, but the columns should go in this order: Open, High, Low, Close, Volume. @Jimmy